# “colorful flowers” or “a colorful bundle of flowers”

Tags: plural-forms, collective-nouns

I have a bundle of a red flower, blue flower, green flower, and purple flower. Are “colorful flowers” and “a colorful bundle of flowers” both acceptable?

Comment: Yes, both  are acceptable.

Comment: And  "a bundle of colorful flowers," might be used too.

Comment: Yes, but the group noun for flowers isn't "bundle"— it's "bouquet." You'd say "colorful flowers" or "a colorful *bouquet* of flowers."

Comment: It's a "bunch" of flowers, rather than a "bundle", or a "bouquet" if it's been arranged to look beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

"A colorful bunch of flowers" and "A bunch of colorful flowers" are both idiomatic.

It would usually be called a *bunch* of flowers rather than a bundle. Or you might call it a *posy* of flowers, though that seems to me a little old-fashioned. If there were *more* flowers - quite a *lot* more - it might be called a *bouquet* of flowers. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bunch+of+flowers%2Cbouquet+of+flowers%2Cbundle+of+flowers%2Cposy+of+flowers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbunch%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbouquet%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbundle%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cposy%20of%20flowers%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Thank you for shooing away the bundle here. :)